# error : liblas/version.hpp : no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, liblas

I want to use liblas to treat some data so I installed the library on my ubuntu 13.04 at /usr/share/include , the automatic path.

I have also a project on code::blocks to use this library.

here is an extract of the main program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <liblas.hpp>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
        std::ifstream ifs;
        ifs.open("myfile.LAS", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        liblas::ReaderFactory f;
        liblas::Reader reader = f.CreateWithStream(ifs);
        liblas::Header const& header = reader.GetHeader();
        std::cout << "Compressed: " << (header.Compressed() == true) ? "true":"false";
        std::cout << "Signature: " << header.GetFileSignature() << '\n';
        std::cout << "Points count: " << header.GetPointRecordsCount() << '\n';
        return 0;
}
```

When I want to compile it, I got the error "liblas/version.hpp : no such file or directory"
Code::Blocks opens liblas.hpp and shows the error :
$#include liblas/version.hpp$

(under <>)

but in fact, there is in the same folder as liblas.hpp a file called version.hpp

What's wrong?

Comment: #include <liblas/liblas.hpp>

Comment: I would check again the install guide.

Comment: Okay, I may have mistaken when installing. But first I'm trying to link all parts of the library to my project via Code::Blocks. My first essay is good : I added version.hpp so it asks for an other file. Perhaps I should find how to link a folder.

Comment: I've relinked more correctly and my new error is : "undefined reference to 'liblas::ReaderFactory::CreateWithStream(std::istream&)' "
and others of the same kind

Comment: I wouldn't expect `/usr/share/include` to be in the default include directories, so you are going to need to get `-I/usr/share/include` to the compiler some how.

Comment: I did it and it appears that the issue remains probably now in the version of myfile.LAS. In fact, libLAS cannot read .LAS 2.0...